# How do I mock Directory.GetFiles?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to figure out how or if it is possible to do the following with Moq

```
public class Download
{
    private IFoo ifoo;

    public Download(IFoo ifoo)
    {
        this.ifoo = ifoo;
    }

    public void Download()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles("filepath"); //<<<===

        foreach (var item in files)
        {

            // do something

        }    
    }
}
```

In unit test.

```
// Arrange 

var mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
mockFoo.setup( s => s.Bar()).returns(true);

var foo = new Foo(mockFoo.Object);

// Act
foo.Download()
```

How can I mock the `files` variable, so the method uses the mock version. Is this even the correct approach? As I am not mocking the class, and rather mocking the dependency how do I go about settings the files variable so it looks at mocked file string[].

Comment: Tightly coupled to static  `Directory`. That should be extracted out and encapsulated behind an abstraction you control

Comment: good point, is there a short term solution that I could use? the abstraction is going to take sometime as this was a simplified example

Comment: Unless you can find a mock library that can weave that call. I think TypeMock can but I am not sure if it is free

Comment: You could probably also check Microsoft Fakes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh549175(v=vs.110)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders?view=aspnetcore-2.1. This contains classes for reading physical files, but also abstractions that can be mocked. So instead of depending on `Directory.GetFiles("filepath")` you would depend on `IFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("path");`

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, it has lead me to think either abstract it, or use a IWrapper for this particular thing and inject that it in

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would need to depend on an abstraction to get your files instead of having a hard dependency on `System.IO.Directory`:

```
public interface IFileProvider
{
    string[] GetFiles(string path);
}

public class PhysicalFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    public string[] GetFiles(string path)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(path);
    }
}
```

You would inject the abstraction in exactly the same way as you're injecting `IFoo`.
Now you can mock `IFileProvider` using Moq, creating a mock that returns exactly the strings that you want it to return.

```
var fileProvider = new Mock<IFileProvider>();
fileProvider.Setup(x => x.GetFiles(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(new[] {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"});
```

You can also use [Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical/2.2.0) which provides both the file system access and the abstraction.

```
public class Download
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider _fileProvider;

    public Download(IFoo foo, IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {
        _foo = foo;
        _fileProvider = fileProvider;
    }

    public void SomethingWithFiles()
    {
        var files = _fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("filepath")
            .Where(item => !item.IsDirectory);

        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            // something
        }
    }
}
```

The concrete implementation would be `PhysicalFileProvider`.

---

One more variation. Instead of injecting an interface, inject a delegate:

```
public delegate string[] GetFilesFunction(string path);

public class Download
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    private readonly GetFilesFunction _getFiles;

    public Download(IFoo foo, GetFilesFunction getFiles)
    {
        _foo = foo;
        _getFiles = getFiles;
    }

...
```

That's even easier to mock. You don't even need Moq.

```
var subject = new Download(mockedFoo, path => new []{"file1.txt","file2.txt"} );
```